# Laravel: Proper Querying Many to Many Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables and a third pivot table as follows:

Table 1: Files

- id
- title

Table 2: Pools

- id
- title
- is_visible (1,0)

Table 3: file_pools

- file_id
- pool_id

All Models and Relationships are in place.

A `File` may belong to none, 1 or more pools

A `Pool` may have none,1 or more files

Now, i would like to create a scope `visible` in the Model `File` such that:

- the query includes any File that belongs to none or 1,or more active Pools
- should not include any File that has at least 1 invisible (is_visible=0) Pool, even if this File belongs to another visible Pool

Below is what I have tried but this includes files that are both in visible and invisible Pools

```
public function scopeVisible($query)
{
    return $query->doesntHave('pools')->orWhereHas('pools', function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_visible',1);
    });
}
```

any help highly welcome

### EDIT: Add Sample Data

```
table: files

| id       |      title    |  
|----------|---------------|
| 1        |  File A       |
| 2        |  File B       |
| 3        |  File C       |
| 4        |  File D       |
```

```
table: pools

| id       |    title      | is_visible|  
|----------|---------------|---------- |
| 1        |  Pool 1       | 1         |
| 2        |  Pool 2       | 0         |
```

```
table: file_pools

| file_id  |     pool_id   |  
|----------|---------------|
| 1        |  1            |
| 2        |  2            |
| 3        |  1            |
| 3        |  2            |
```

```
The Expected Result : (scope:visible)

| id       |     title     |  
|----------|---------------|
| 1        |  File A       |
| 4        |  File D       |
```

Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly:

```php
public function scopeVisible($query)
{
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('pools', function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_visible', 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: this is similar to what i already have and doesn't really solves the problem.In my final Collection, i would like to see either a file that don't belong to any pool, or 
 a file that belong to a visible pool, but reject a file that belongs to an invisible pool even if it belongs to another visible pool

Comment: That's what this query does. What would be sample data where the result is incorrect?

Comment: I have edited and added sample data and expected result

Comment: I get the expected result when I use `File::visible()->get()`. What do you get?

Comment: it gives me File A, File B, File D. its expected that File B should not be included because it belongs to at least a Pool which is not visible.

Comment: actually it worked. i had overlooked some extra data in db